# Calculate week number from the date based on the Fiscal year defined by us in Excel . Week is counted as Sunday to Saturday

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My Fiscal year starts from 1st Feb :

```
Date
02/01/2019
02/02/2019
02/05/2019
02/14/2019
```

I want the week number to be extracted ( Year wise and the continuous weeks) in excel starting from this date and my week  starts form (Sunday to Saturday)

So my output looks like :

```
Date        Week_year_wise   Week_continuous
02/01/2019  1                1
02/02/2019  1                1
02/05/2019  2                2
02/14/2019  3                3
...         ..               ..
...         ..               ..
02/1/2020   1                54
02/7/2020   2                55
02/14/2020  3                56
```

Comment: Your date format is `mm/dd/yyyy`?   (which is NOT obvious on an international used site like SO)

Comment: Is the week that contains `1-Feb` always the first week of the fiscal year; or is it the `1-Feb` starts the first week, and `31-Jan` would always be in the previous fiscal week?

Comment: Or possibly is Week 1 the week in February that starts with the first Sunday of the month.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld My Fiscal Year starts from 1st Feb till 31st jan and Week starts from Sunday till Saturday .

Answer (score 1):

- if 02/01/2019 in cell A2
- in B2 formula: =A2-$A$2+WEEKDAY($A$2;1)-1
- in C2 formula: =(B2-MOD(B2;7))/7+1

In C2 you will see the fiscal weeknumber.

```
DATE                FISCWEEK
vr 01-02-2019   5   1
za 02-02-2019   6   1
zo 03-02-2019   7   2
ma 04-02-2019   8   2
di 05-02-2019   9   2
wo 06-02-2019   10  2
do 07-02-2019   11  2
vr 08-02-2019   12  2
za 09-02-2019   13  2
zo 19-01-2020   357 52
ma 20-01-2020   358 52
di 21-01-2020   359 52
wo 22-01-2020   360 52
do 23-01-2020   361 52
vr 24-01-2020   362 52
za 25-01-2020   363 52
zo 26-01-2020   364 53
ma 27-01-2020   365 53
di 28-01-2020   366 53
wo 29-01-2020   367 53
do 30-01-2020   368 53
vr 31-01-2020   369 53
za 01-02-2020   370 53
zo 02-02-2020   371 54
ma 03-02-2020   372 54
di 04-02-2020   373 54
wo 05-02-2020   374 54
```

BTW: daynames are Dutch, date-format - DD-MM-YYYY

EDIT: To start with week one at the beginning of the year, a change is needed in the formula in cell B2.

The current formula is: `=A2-$A$2+WEEKDAY($A$2;1)-1`
In this formula `$A$2` points to the first day of the year.

If this is changed to `DATE(YEAR(A2);2;1)` then the end of year goes OK, but there will be a problem with weeknrs in january, therefore changing this formula to `=A2-DATE(YEAR(A2);2;1)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A2);2;1);1)-1` is only part of the solution.

Because the fault is only in january this can be solved like this (no explanation here... , try to find out what it does, and learn):

`=A2-DATE(YEAR(A2)-IF(MONTH(A2)=1;1;0);2;1)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A2)-IF(MONTH(A2)=1;1;0);2;1);1)-1`

Now i only hope i did not make any translating error in the function names, because i have a Dutch version of Excel, en Microsoft is not smart enough to understand that function names should NEVER be translated!
BTW: they did, finally! (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/language-accessory-pack-for-office-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f#ID0EAADAAA=Office_2013), now i can use English function names )

Comment: I don't believe you can have 54 weeks in a fiscal year -- see your entries `02-02-2020` and later.

Comment: True, that's the only check i did not do for @Mighty 

Comment: Well, that is how he has it in his continuous example.

Comment: Thanks @Luuk  . I can see the continuos week number and can i have week_year_wise too which should ideally restart when 1st Feb of the next year comes

Comment: This is SO, a place where you should solve your own solution for a problem, and get some help for difficult problems. I already gave you half the solution, the rest is up to you , it's not that hard to write some formula's in Excel, try it yourself. 

Comment: BTW: Can you confirm that 31st Jan 2021 is in Fiscal week 54 ???